# Fix permissions after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: apt, permissions, 16.04

I updated a server from 14.04 to 16.04. Now `apt-get update` does not work anymore. I get the following errors:

```
0% [2 InRelease gpgv 11.5 kB] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.26)]
dpkg: warning: failed to open configuration file '/root/.dpkg.cfg' for reading: Permission denied
/usr/bin/apt-key: 316: /usr/bin/apt-key: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
gpgv: Signature made Thu Apr 28 20:16:42 2016 CEST using DSA key ID 437D05B5
gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found
```

I can see that some child-processes of `apt-get` are running as user `_apt`, but I don’t know how to check `apt-key` and `dpkg`.

`scp` from a remote host also doesn’t work anymore with a similar error message:

```
Couldn't open /dev/null: Permission denied
```

Currently `ls -alh /dev/null` gives

```
crw------- 1 root root 1, 3 Apr 26 12:51 /dev/null
```

How can I fix the permissions?
Maybe somebody with a fresh 16.04 install can give a comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/dev/null` should have `0666` permissions and that is what `/etc/udev/rules.d/device-permissions.rules` says:

```
KERNEL=="null|zero|full|random|urandom", MODE="0666"
```

But unfortunately this is a virtual server. So the kernel has not been updated:

```
# uname -a
Linux memocamp 2.6.32-042stab063.2 #1 SMP Tue Oct 23 16:24:09 MSK 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

A temporary fix is to manually set the permissions:

```
chmod go+rw /dev/null
```